# is using regression for recommender is still collaborative filtering?

Tags: regression, recommender-system

I am confused about how can implementing regression to recommend books ratings be an item-based collaborative filtering? Can you elaborate?

Comment: [Cross-posted on AI](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/45001/25529)